# Are non-specific code-style questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

Taking these two examples from the last 24 hours for comparison

**Migrated**

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58630/how-far-should-var-and-null-coalescing-operator-be-entertained-without-ham

**Not migrated**

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/should-if-statments-be-in-inner-or-outer-method

Where is the line we are drawing here?

The former has no code sample, which I assume is why it was spotted as not being relevant to CodeReview. The latter has a code sample but it really offers nothing to the question, except clarification.

I am perfectly happy with going in a different direction from StackOverflow and saying that questions should be specific rather than vague, containing an actual and complete code sample, but we should have a clear line and stick to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed the one that wasn't migrated.  The other was flagged, so I noticed it this morning when I had a moment.  Style questions like that don't belong here as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I fear there are many existing questions like that but fair enough, I shall flag them if I see them in future.

Answer (score 1):

> I am perfectly happy with going in a different direction from StackOverflow and saying that questions should be specific rather than vague, containing an actual and complete code sample, but we should have a clear line and stick to it.

Obviously (I hope) a good code sample is *required* on a site titled "Code Review."

But how can a question be vague if it has a code sample?

Comment: like this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/58688/should-if-statments-be-in-inner-or-outer-method

Comment: @pdr I see, that helps explain what you mean